# Unity OnLevelWasLoaded not being called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script called StartGame that is suposed to do different things when different game modes are selected. Unity's API and forums suggests using OnLevelWasLoaded, but it isnt being called. In fact when I hover my mouse over it in Visual Studio it tells me the method is"StartGame.OnLevelWasLoaded". I'm pretty sure that means that It isn't overriding the method. Has anyone else had this problem? Also I'm using Unity 5.3.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code?

Comment: Unity finds methods by reflection, not by overriding. The tooltip doesn't matter--we do need to see code.

Comment: There are indeed many threads about that issue. Here's one http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1112017/onlevelwasloaded-not-called-at-all.html. We also faced that issue but only in editor. @31eee384 On a side note, despite the common idea that reflection is used for callbacks, well, it is not. http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/

Comment: @fafase It's still reflecting over the code, right? Just not with `System.Reflection`. Thanks for the link though--I didn't know specifically what was happening, and I certainly won't call it reflection anymore.

Comment: I guess that is internal functioning of their own. I can't say for sure what is happening, there has been this idea for long that it was reflection, even I thought it was reflection coz it looks like it. Seems to be more of a file reading, searching for a specific string and then assigning memory location of the method to a collection of delegates. Kinda weird coz it is not in intellisense so it would not know about the method, but if you try to implement wrong, it knows about it (parameter in Update). Kinda weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your GameObject is still existing after loading the new scene?
Usually, all GameObjects are deleted from the scene when loading another scene.

You can prevent this by loading the scene additive (adding the contents of the new scene to the contents of the current one)

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("your scene name", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```

or by preventing deletion for your specific GameObject

```
GameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad(yourStartGameScriptHolder); // where yourStartGameScriptHolder is the GameObject(!), not the script reference
```